# Input amount for a PayPal Buy Now button?

Tags: button, input, paypal

I'd like the user to be able to type the amount they wish to pay into a text box, then click "Buy Now", and that amount will be charged through PayPal. How do I go about creating a PayPal button like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Success! For anyone else having this problem, here is the code I used:

```
<form name="input" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="YOUR BUSINESS NAME">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="ITEM NAME">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="ITEM ID NUMBER">
Other amount: $<input type="text" maxlength="200" style="width:50px;" name="amount" value="5.00"> CAD<br />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
</form>
```